# How to mock DB Queries in Kotlin's Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, mocking, kotlin-exposed

I'm currently writing an application using the Kotlin ORM Exposed. I am trying to test some basic functionality where I convert the query results to an instance of the corresponding object. I have something along the lines of the following:

```kotlin
    suspend fun getAllFoo(): List<Foo> = newSuspendedTransaction {
        FooTable.selectAll().map { rowToFoo(it) }
    }

    private fun rowToFoo(row: ResultRow): Foo {
        return Foo(
            id = row[Foo.id],
            description = row[Foo.description]
        )
    }
```

(bare with me as I omit the code for the data class, as I don't think it's super relevant). My question is, how do I mock the `selectAll()` function? I have tried

```
        val mockFoo = mock<Foo> {
            on { selectAll() }.doReturn(???)
        }
```

but I do not know what to add to the mocked return, because the query results seem to be somewhat cryptic internal classes, any ideas?

Comment: You can mock the caller one level up. Instead of mocking database calls directly, mock the function which wraps database calls. According to your code I'd mock `getAllFoo ` and return `listOf(Foo(...), Foo(...))` thus separating repository logic.

Comment: @kdev I'm actually trying to test the ```rowToFoo``` method, so unfortunately the only way to do that is to mock the ```selectAll``` method